# open tab with anchor link

Tags: javascript, html

i have 3 tabs on the end of the page
i want that the link on the top will go all the way down and open the tab
what is the best way?
thanks

**this is the links on the top:**

```
<div class="tab">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Tokyo')"></a>
</div>
<div class="tab2">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Paris')"></a>
</div>
<div class="tab3">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
'London')"></a>
</div>
```

**and this is the tabs**

```
    <div id="close" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">  
[insert page='246' display='content']
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">   
[insert page='244' display='content']
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">  
[insert page='193' display='content']
</div>


<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", 
"");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("close").click();
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Unless you tell us the precise problem you're facing, I'd suggest that the 'best' way (you may have to also define what you mean by 'best' in the question) would be to use HTML: `<a href="#London">Go to London</a>`; avoiding the (potentially) unnecessary JavaScript.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to use jQuery for animation, `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(container).offset().top-30}, 1000);` where `container` is your `London`, `Paris` `Tokyo` div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the href links:

```
    <div class="tab">
    <a href="#Tokyo" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
    'Tokyo')"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab2">
    <a href="#Paris" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
    'Paris')"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab3">
    <a href="#London" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
    'London')"></a>
    </div>
```

Clicking the links will scroll the page automatically to the anchor